# Object Defined error when adding data validation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create data validation in a cell based on a string as the address. This string is saved from a worksheet.

In this example the `strAddress` returns `$G$3:$G$14`.

I get

> Object-defined error

when adding the validation as indicated by * in the code.

This is half the routine, as the rest are repetitions of this:

```
Sub UpdateLists(advertiser As String)

'    On Error Resume Next

    'need to update the other data validation based on the advertiser selected
    Dim strAdvertiser As String, strAddress As String
    Dim adRng As Range
    Dim myRng As Range

    'clear validation first
    Range("I10:I12").Validation.Delete

    strAdvertiser = advertiser

    'now find the relevant supplier in the lists sheet
    Set adRng = Sheets("Lists").Range("A:A").Find(What:=strAdvertiser)

    If Not adRng Is Nothing Then

        'adjust division according to advertiser
        Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Division")

        If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
            'list range
            strAddress = adRng.Offset(0, 1).Text

            'adjust list
            '**error on below line
            myRng.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='Lists'!" & strAddress

        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to find Division", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End if
End Sub
```

I have tried:

a) removing the `myRng` object and using `Sheets`, but this still returns the error.

b) hard-coding the `strAddress`.

c) running several `Debug.Print` on the `myRng` object to check it's validity.

d) to use `.Validation.Modify` originally, but then have moved to `.Validation.Delete` and `.Validation.Add`.

Comment: @BigBen it is defined in the above post. See: `strAddress` returns `$G$3:$G$14`

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Seems to me that in older versions, you cannot use validation from a range on another worksheet.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016. And yes, the `Lists` sheet exists.

Comment: @Dean Can you try removing `ActiveSheet` and fully qualifying that line? Just in case :). Also fully qualify `Range("I10:I12").Validation.Delete`.

Comment: @dwirony thanks for this, it works now. Perhaps you could elaborate as to why using `ActiveSheet` would cause issues?

Comment: @dwirony if you post answer with explanation I can mark as answered, thanks.

Comment: @Dean Either one of those could've been the issue - maybe you were deleting validation on the wrong sheet (so it'd be similar to the problem FunThomas brought up), or you were establishing `myRng` incorrectly by finding Division on the wrong worksheet. Either way, fully qualifying all your ranges will probably save you many headaches in the future! :)

Comment: @Dean I'm going to guess you were deleting validation on the wrong worksheet, so FunThomas was pretty much spot on with his solution - might as well give him the credit :)

Comment: @Dean here's a primer on why (and how) to avoid using Activate/Select: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 2):

I think you must clear any existing validation before you set the validation to a list.

Try to change the code to

```
With myRng.Offset(0, 1)
    .Validation.Delete
    .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='Lists'!" & strAddress
End With
```

Comment: I thought this initially as well, but it looks like he might do that here: `Range("I10:I12").Validation.Delete`

Comment: Yes @dwirony you are correct. My apologies I was not clear about that

Comment: @Dean Are you certain that the offset from `myRng` is always within `"I10:I12"`? Why not just do `myRng.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete` before you add just in case.

Comment: @dwirony yes, `Debug.Print myRng.Address` returns `H10:H12`. I added the `Validation.Delete` in my debugging process.